# Running heavy PHP scripts in background

Tags: php, linux, background-process

I want to run more than 800 PHP scripts in the background simultaneously on Linux. Each PHP script will execute forever, meaning it will not stop once it has started. Each script will send request and get response from the server. How much RAM do I need for that? Will it possible to run more than 800 scripts? What kind of hardware do I need?

Comment: First of all PHP is not good solution to do that kind of things. You may consider to use some Perl or Python. And why you need 800 at once? You can execute one in loop

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that. No it is impossible to tell you how much MB or RAM or what kind of hardware you need. [Yes this smells like an XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably doing it wrong. Since your scripts are I/O bound instead of CPU bound, an event loop will help you. That way you just need as many workers as CPU cores.

This approach does not only lower your required resources in terms of memory and CPU cycles, but also reduce the number of scripts you have to monitor.

There are various PHP implementations, here are the three most popular ones:

- [Amp](https://github.com/amphp/amp)
- [Icicle](https://github.com/icicleio/icicle)
- [React](https://github.com/reactphp/react)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I wonder how it would be an I/O bound ? Since I'm going to use socket operation. What is the difference between I/O and CPU ?

Comment: @JohnMcLow: If you do socket operations, most of the time will be spent waiting for I/O (I/O bound) instead of calculating things on your CPU (CPU bound).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm sure the hardware you seek exists, but you will need a time machine to access it ... do you have a time machine ??

I'm going to assume you do not have access to, or plans to build a time machine, and say that this is not sensible.

In case humour didn't do it for you; There is no hardware that is capable of executing that many processes concurrently, setting out to create an architecture that requires more threads than any commonly available hardware can execute is clearly a bad idea.

If all you are doing is I/O, then you should use non-blocking, asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm going to perform socket related operations for each script. What should I use to perform that kind of operation ?

Answer (score -3):

To figure out how much ram you will need is simple, how much data will be stored in memory during execution x 800.

You can improve memory usage by setting variables to null as soon as you are done with the data, even if you are re-using the variables again I would highly recommend this. That way the execution will not turn into a memory leak filling up RAM and crashing your server.

```
$myVariable = null; //clears memory
```

The second part of your question "execute forever" is easy too, you simply need to tell PHP to allow the script to run for a long time... Personally though I would do the following:

1. Setup 800 crons of your script all running every 1 hour.
2. I would assume your script is in an infinite loop... note the time into a variable before the infinite loop and in the loop check if 1 hour has passed, if 1 hour has passed end the loop and the process (a new one will replace it).

Doing the above will ensure the process will be cleaned every hour, also if for some reason a process gets killed by the server due to resource or security checks the process will spring back up within the hour.

Of course you could lower this to 30 mins, 15 mins, 5 mins depending on how heavy each loop is and how often you want to re-establish the processes.